# How can I see the list of recent opened files in Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers

How can I see the list of recent opened files in Numbers? Is this supported at all?

Answer (score 3):

- Many native macOS apps do support "Open Recent". It is under Files menu, often clubbed with "Open" item.

  > [image]
- You can also use Help menu to search items in other menus.